# wiremock - Update changes in json file even jar is running

Tags: wiremock

I am new to WireMock and currently understanding standalone jar functionality.

Is there any way that we can do changes in .json file which is under mapping folder and don't want to run jar again and again. i.e. to do changes in json files even when jar is running.

Thanks,
Manan

Answer (score 0):

Old question but with no answer. this answer may help others.

> Is there any way that we can do changes in .json file which is under
> mapping folder and don't want to run jar again and again. i.e. to do
> changes in json files even when jar is running.

Yes, you can.

You can use curl with the POST method to send a request to __admin/mappings/reset endpoint.

This will trigger a reload of the stubs on the file system without a restart as given below:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/__admin/mappings/reset
```

Or Run the powershel script:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Uri http://localhost:8080/__admin/mappings/reset
```

To check the new mapping, suppose you run mocknet in port 8080, run in browser

```
http://localhost:8080/__admin/mappings
```